# How can I insert a Keyframe and Modifier to a custom node group value in blender?

Tags: python, nodes, blender

In my script, I press a button and it adds a custom node group. I would love to be able to know how to add a keyframe for a value and then add an Fcurve Modifier 'Noise' and then be able to change the Scale value on the Group node. I know this will be simple to most (if not all) of you, but I am really stuck..Normally I can find the right code in snippets or answers online but I can not find anything about this and I would appreciate the help!..

Since I am really new, I don't know most of the correct context/syntax and so on.

I tried what I normally do to change a value and just tried code I thought might work like,

```
group_node.inputs[2].anim.keyframe_insert
```

Now that's obviously wrong but I am not sure how to approach this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a material node group called "myGroup", you add it to the active objects material with

```
obj = bpy.context.object
mat = obj.active_material
group_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
group_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['myGroup']
```

To adjust a nodes input value, you set the sockets `default_value` property.

```
group_node.inputs[0].default_value = 0.75
```

You can also access input sockets by name

```
mat.node_tree.nodes['Mix Shader'].inputs['Fac'].default_value
```

Now the tricky part to creating keyframes is knowing where the [animation data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AnimData.html) is stored. Objects hold most animation data, which is found in [`obj.animation_data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.animation_data). So if you want to keyframe the objects location you set `obj.location = (x,y,z)` you then tell the object to [insert a keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) for the data path of `location` with

```
obj.keyframe_insert('location', frame=1)
```

Note that you don't need to change the current frame, you set the value of a property and then insert a keyframe, specifying which frame it will be on.

As materials can be used with more than one object, they have their own animation data which is found in its node tree `mat.node_tree.animation.data`. So to animate a value in a materials node, you tell its node tree to insert the keyframe and give it the data path which is the python path from the node tree to the value.

```
dpath = 'nodes["Group"].inputs[0].default_value'
mat.node_tree.keyframe_insert(dpath, frame=1)
```

The [fcurves](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html) are stored in `animation_data.action.fcurves`. To get the one you want, you can find it by its data path, for array values like location you also specify an `index` to which sub-value you want.

```
fc = mat.node_tree.animation_data.action.fcurves.find(dpath)
```

Now that you have the fcurve, add a [modifier](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurveModifiers.html) and set some of its properties.

```
nmod = fc.modifiers.new("NOISE")
nmod.scale = 1.25
nmod.phase = 2.3
nmod.strength = 0.7
nmod.depth = 1.35
nmod.offset = 0.23
```

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear, this sounds like what I need but for the Texture Node Editor, not the Shader Node Editor. I want to add a keyframe to a Node value. Then add a modifier to control that value.

Comment: @Darkfall Instead of `mat.node_tree` use `tex.node_tree`, the path to `node_tree` may vary but everything else will be the same.